# InteliJ 2018.1 - no Run option for Java file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I just downloaded new InteliJ 2018.1.4 and tried to test simple Spring Boot application:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git
```

But after downloading project and opening whole folder/project inside InteliJ and opening Java file - there is no option to `run` Java file.

What could be the reason? (I have JDK installed on my mac machine)

Bellow is example showing - no Run option inside Java file:
[image: InteliJ example - no run option for Java]Run -> Edit Configurations:

[image]

[image: Project settings][image: Project SDK]
[image: Run]`[![enter image description here][6]][6]`
[image: default]

Comment: In your Mac toolbar menu for IntelliJ IDEA, under `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...`, is there a value filled in for `JRE`?

Comment: @davedwards - added another picture for your question.

Comment: In the Project window, please right click gs-spring-boot -> open module settings -> check Project tab for SDK and SDKs tab for installed SDKs

Comment: @baao - added pictures for these 2.

Comment: That looks correct. Can you press shift + command + a, then type run and see what comes there?

Comment: @baao - added pictures for that. After Default comes up - it happens - 'nothing'.

Comment: Very strange, clicking run leads to nothing too? I’d try to reinstall... Another thing you could try is to start IntelliJ from the command line, this would at least yield errors if any. I can only guess from here though... :-(

Comment: How do you start InteliJ from command line?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting the java folder as sources root  [image]

Additionally you can (initialize) refresh, build gradle project